# Linkedin company search gives no results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, linkedin-api

I'm trying to do a company search with the country code `na.us`. 
I'm using the [linkedin-oauth2](https://github.com/emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2) gem.

I'm able to get some results when I do company search with `location,us`

```
api.company_search(
  keyword:"technologies", 
  facets: "location,industry", 
  facet: ["location,us","industry,4"], 
  start: 0, 
  count: 1000000
)
```

But when querying with country `location,na.us`, which [is specified in the docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/reference/geography-codes) then I get zero results.

```
api.company_search(
  keyword:"technologies", 
  facets: "location,industry", 
  facet: ["location,na.us","industry,4"], 
  start: 0, 
  count: 1000000
)
```

Also i'm not able to query with the [company-size parameter](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/reference/company-size-codes).